# How to create new message using JSQMessageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift4, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am pretty close to publishing an application on the iOS app store that uses JSQMessageController. However, every tutorial I have seen does not show how to use the given UI to create a new conversation. Right now, I have a pretty janky UI that takes in who the message is suppose to go to, and the message. However, I was hoping to use the same UI given in JSQMessageController, however with a "To" bar. Has anyone done this before and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to watch this serie of video from YouTube in order to create new message using JSQMessageViewController:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOd8RHY-ryc&list=PLM-WD6b2B_nJoIkl7SfFiBrloNJ3zfU6n

But he used Firebase so if you don't use it, you just can have a look then you can changed some piece of code for your own database.

Hope it helps.